# M14 FinalityFlow: Signature Verification failed

Tags: corda

This only occurs in M14 -
I have a signed transaction stx. First, I sendAndReceive(anotherParty, stx) for some parties to give them a chance to verify the integrity for the transaction and verifySignaturesExcept(notaryPubKey). Then I run subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx)), and FinalityFlow fails with SignatureException.  But if I use a clone such as subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx.copy()), it works fine.
BTW, sendAndReceive(anotherParty, stx.copy()) and subFlow(FinalityFlow(stx)) are no good.

Why is that?

\Sean

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here would be to replicate the issue in a test on a MockNetwork (see some basic examples here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-tutorial/blob/master/kotlin-source/src/test/kotlin/com/example/flow/IOUFlowTests.kt).

Once you've replicated the issue on a MockNetwork, it should be easy to step through with the debugger and work out if the transaction is missing any signatures at the time `FinalityFlow` is invoked.

Comment: I figured it out - the ContractState's participants changed before stx is sent to other parties for validation.  What is strange is that the other parties still get the original participants while the FinalityFlow gets the modified one.  Ideally, the other parties should throw a TransactionVerificationException.

Comment: Also, it should have failed in M13 but did not.  Is that due to the serialization work for M14?